# How to combine exisiting full screen mode and video pause?

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

I somehow managed to put two options in one button: when clicking, the video starts to play and enters full screen at the same time.

This is the html:

```
<video id="video1" class="video-small">
<source src="video/Marinela+Pinguinos-HD.mp4" type="video/mp4" class="video-file">
<source src="video/Marinela_Pinguinos-HD.webm" type="video/webm" class="video-file">
</video>

<button id="play" class="full-play-button" onclick="vidplay(); goFullscreen('video1')">Play fullscreen</button>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function vidplay() {
   var video = document.getElementById("video1");
   var button = document.getElementsByClassName("full-play-button");
   if (video.paused) {
      video.play();
      button.textContent = "||";
   } else {
      video.pause();
      button.textContent = ">";
   }
}

function goFullscreen(id) {
// Get the element that we want to take into fullscreen mode
var element = document.getElementById(id);

// These function will not exist in the browsers that don't support fullscreen mode yet, 
// so we'll have to check to see if they're available before calling them.

if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
  // This is how to go into fullscren mode in Firefox
  // Note the "moz" prefix, which is short for Mozilla.
  element.mozRequestFullScreen();
} else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
  // This is how to go into fullscreen mode in Chrome and Safari
  // Both of those browsers are based on the Webkit project, hence the same prefix.
  element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
}
}
```

So far things go smooth. When entering full screen, there's a default player-like thing at the bottom, with a button offering the possibility to exit full screen.

What I would like to achieve is to be able to pause the video when clicking that button, but I have no idea how.

What I can think of is some kind of a function that detects if we're full screen or not, and if we're not, it would pause/stop (not sure which I prefer yet) the video.

This is what came to my mind, but I'm really a newbie in JS and it doesn't work:

```
 function exitPause() {

      var video = document.getElementById("video1");

    if (document.exitFullscreen) {
        video.pause();
    }
    else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
        video.pause();
    }
    else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
        video.pause();
    }
    else if (element.msExitFullscreen) {
        video.pause();
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I make it happen?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`fullscreenchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/fullscreenchange) event handler:

```
video.addEventListener(
  'fullscreenchange',
  function(event) {
    if (!document.fullscreenElement) {
      video.pause();
    }
  },
  false
);
```

Note: care for vendor prefixes.

Comment: The `fullscreenchange` event fires whenever the fullscreen mode is toggled. If there is no fullscreen element, then `document.fullscreenElement` returns `null`. Thus `!document.fullscreenElement` inside the event handler is executed on exit from fullscreen mode. Check this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/894Mf/).

Comment: Thank you! I used exactly this except s/full/webkitfull/ and now my video works on Android the same as it does on iOS. I really appreciate that you didn't use the JQuery shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Igor Gilyazov I managed to go a bit further. This is how the code looks now:

```
 function vidplay() {
   var video = document.getElementById("video1");
   var button = document.getElementsByClassName("full-play-button");


   video.addEventListener(
   'webkitfullscreenchange',
    function(event) {

  if (!document.fullscreenElement && video.paused)  {
  video.play();

} 

else {
    video.pause();
    }
},
false
);


}
```

and going full screen:

```
function goFullscreen(id) {
// Get the element that we want to take into fullscreen mode
var element = document.getElementById(id);

// These function will not exist in the browsers that don't support fullscreen mode yet, 
// so we'll have to check to see if they're available before calling them.

if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
  // This is how to go into fullscren mode in Firefox
  // Note the "moz" prefix, which is short for Mozilla.
  element.mozRequestFullScreen();
} else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
  // This is how to go into fullscreen mode in Chrome and Safari
  // Both of those browsers are based on the Webkit project, hence the same prefix.
  element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
}
// Hooray, now we're in fullscreen mode!
}
```

What happens now is when I first click the button, it goes full screen and the video plays. When going back to small screen, it pauses.

This is great.

Unfortunately it happens only every second time (the next time it keeps being paused no matter if going full or small, then right again, then wrong and so on).

I know I'm close, but it's not fully working yet, any ideas for modifications?